# how to get a value from a $.get request and send it as a return value immediately

Tags: jquery

I need to grab the value from a route using $.get.
I got it but I cannot wait up to all the others functions be finished to return the value.

```
function myFunction(str) { // str is my word to be searched.
    var obj = {str};
    $.get('/pronunciation/words'+'?'+$.param(obj), function( data ) {
    // I would like to pass data straightway after the line above. 
    return data;
});
```

Comment: That's not how `$.get` works - it's asynchronous.  see here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m for pass me the link, I am still struggle thinking how to fix that issue. I cannot see another way to handle it.

Comment: Ok.  In your `myFunction`, return the $.get, ie `return $.get(...` then in your calling function, use `.done()` - ie  `myFunction("hello").done(function(data) { .... });`.  Otherwise you need to rethink your design.